# Api curl script is not showing output in my unix terminal

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote a curl script to pull data from my api url into my unix terminal. But when I run the script below, I get a blank space as my output, rather than data from the api url. I don't get any standard error message, just a blank space followed by $ to enter a new command.

```
#!/bin/bash
INSTANCE_NAME="https://servicenow.com/ServiceNowData/tickets?ticks=4320000"
DATA_OUTPUT=$(curl -s -k -X GET -H "accept: application/json" $INSTANCE_NAME)

echo $DATA_OUTPUT
```

Comment: So then why did you specify the `-s` option? Do `-Ss`

Comment: I intended to dismiss the progress and error message, but trying with -Ss, I see the SSL protocol error (35)

Comment: `see the SSL protocol error` Please post the full error message

Comment: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to servicenow.com:443

Answer (score 0):

Page 404. And `-H "Accept-Encoding: application/json"`

Comment: I'll try this. I specified the silent option because it was returning an SSL error